# How to get the value of each cell in a row and assign it to a text box in that row

Tags: html, jquery

How to get the value of each cell in a row and assign it to the value of the text box in that row?

```
<tr>
    <td class="oridinal-number">1</td>
    <td class="number"> 123456</td>
    <td class="name"> Name </td>
    <td class="input"><input name="text" value="here value from first oridinal number td number and td name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="oridinal-number">2</td>
    <td class="number"> 123456789</td>
    <td class="name"> Name </td>
    <td class="input"><input name="text-194" value="here value from first oridinal number td number and td name"></td>
</tr>

                        (function ($) {
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('tr td').each(function () {
                                //alert($(this).html());
                                //console.log($(this).attr('value'));
                                var name = ($(this).attr('value'));
                                console.log(name);
                                //console.log($('.nazwa').attr('value'));
                                $('input[name="text-194"]').val($('input[name="text-194"]').val() + name);

                            });
                        });
                    })(jQuery);
```

Now input value is always last value from td

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "tr" ).each(function( index ) {
  number = $(this).find('.ordinal-number').val();
  name = $(this).find('.name').val();
  $(this).find('.input input').val(number+" "+name);
});
```

or something like that